# GWT - How to detect if we are on the same machine as the server

Tags: gwt, local

I`m currently developing a gwt application on a embedded device (linux with touchscreen) the server and client is started on the device.

I want my client to detect if it`s on the device or not.  Because some screen are not available when connecting remotely

[image]

Comment: Your client would be connecting to localhost then, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a call to the server first and check there if it was made from remote or local address. A response from server should indicate if show screen "A" or not. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Deferred binding might be the answer. GWT [MobileWebApp](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.4.0/samples/mobilewebapp/) sample app uses it to discern the form factor of the target in [FormFactor.gwt.xml](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.4.0/samples/mobilewebapp/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/sample/mobilewebapp/FormFactor.gwt.xml). In essence you define a property and write a provider which determines its value. You then read the property and deliver the appropriate View (in the MVP sense).

BTW I am developing an app for a similar scenario and I'm thinking of reimplementing my solution: reading a URL query parameter which is only present in the browser on the embedded device. Not too awesome. The aforementioned example should allow better hiding of the embedded platform identifier.